# Convert connect-redux-shorthand notation to JS/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux

While I searched & read around, I am still a newbie (or to be exact, a rusty, part-time JS developer) and my question may be awfully simple.

I am trying to convert an existing JS project to TypeScript. I am struggeling to understand the combination of connect-redux-decorator, JS shorthand notation and arrow nomenclature in one single line:

```
@connect(({session: { loggedIn }}) => ({loggedIn}), {establishConnection})
```

I would be very grateful, if someone could translate it to an "export default connect" approach or just a functions/classes notation.

In the following code the line results in this TypeScript error message:

```
[ts]
Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<{}, never>, any> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<{}>; }' is 
not assignable to type 'typeof AuthenticatedApp'.
Type 'Component<Pick<{}, never>, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'AuthenticatedApp'.
Property 'componentDidMount' is optional in type 
'Component<Pick<{}, never>, any, any>' but required in type 'AuthenticatedApp'.`
```

The code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Connecting from '../components/Connecting'
import { establishConnection } from '../actions/login'

@connect(({session: { loggedIn }}) => ({loggedIn}), {establishConnection})
export default class AuthenticatedApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.establishConnection()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(!nextProps.loggedIn) {
      this.props.establishConnection()
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { loggedIn, children } = this.props
    const appContent = loggedIn ? children : <Connecting />

    return (
      <div>
        {appContent}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

While the error message itself may be also solved totally differently I wanted to replace the decorator by "plain" code, hoping that it solves the issue.

My try looked liked something like this (totally wrong, I know):

```
function mapStateToProps(loggedIn) {
   return {loggedIn} = session: { loggedIn };
}
...
class AuthenticatedApp extends React.Component {
...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, establishConnection)(AuthenticatedApp);
```

I am using
Visual Studio Code (1.26.1)
"@types/react": "^16.4.13"
"@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7"
"typescript": "^3.0.3"

Thank you!

HerrB92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starting point, you would take the exact same `connect` call expression and apply it to the component manually instead of using a decorator:

```
export default connect(({session: { loggedIn }}) => ({loggedIn}), {establishConnection})(AuthenticatedApp);
```

(And remove `export default` from the class.)  Now you'll get a (not very clear) error because TypeScript can't infer the parameter type of the `mapStateToProps` function.  You can annotate it like this:

```
export default connect(({session: { loggedIn }}: {session: {loggedIn: boolean}}) => ({loggedIn}), {establishConnection})(AuthenticatedApp);
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(Maybe you have a type already defined in your codebase that contains `{session: {loggedIn: boolean}}` or even more.)

Alternatively, you can pull out the `mapStateToProps` function, leaving it as an arrow function:

```
const mapStateToProps =
  ({session: { loggedIn }}: {session: {loggedIn: boolean}}) => ({loggedIn});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {establishConnection})(AuthenticatedApp);
```

or convert it to a traditional `function` definition:

```
function mapStateToProps({session: { loggedIn }}: {session: {loggedIn: boolean}}) {
  return {loggedIn};
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {establishConnection})(AuthenticatedApp);
```

Ultimately, to compile the component successfully, you'll need to specify its props type, something like this:

```
class AuthenticatedApp extends React.Component<{establishConnection: () => void, loggedIn: boolean}> { ... }
```

but that's a separate issue from the `connect`.

Comment: Awesome, all problems solved! If you don't mind: If I would had to replace "({session: { loggedIn }}: {session: {loggedIn:boolean}}) => ({loggedIn})" by a "mapStateToProps" function (which would match common examples I found), how would it look like?

Comment: I added it to the answer.